# Suprisingly small limits of the calculator written in C

Tags: c, calculator

My task is to write a calculator, which accepts only valid operands, that is, `* / + - ^`. The calculator has to evaluate (check the validity) of the line being entered. For example, it accepts only lines of the following form: `20 + 9`, `8 ^ 2`, etc. If someone entered `9y`, `20+2` or `exit`, the expression would be evaluated to 0. Then the user has to have the possibility of displaying lines, which were entered, regardless of their validity. (Switch E for invalid lines, switch V for valid lines, if valid line is entered and V is chosen it also displays the value of an expression).
Let's now consider the example in order to see how it works.

Line: `20 + 20`

```
Switch: E
Output: There's nothing wrong with the line 20 + 20.
Switch: V
Output: The result is 40.
Line: 20r
Switch: E: 
Output: The line is 20r
Switch: V:
Output: The line 20r is invalid.
```

**The problem**:
Every time I enter a line, which would have the result of calculation more then, I guess `7000` (it doesn't work for `8 * 900`), it doesn't even allow me to choose the `char` for the switch. It displays the line `Choose E for...` and then automatically `You haven't chosen the valid option of the switch.`.

`MAIN.C`:

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "evalexpression.h"

int main() {

char string[100];
int result;
result = InterCalc(string);
CalcFilter(result, string);
return 0;

}
```

EVALEXPRESSION.C

```
#include "stdio.h"
#include "string.h"
#include "evalexpression.h"
#include "math.h"
#include "float.h"

static float f1, f2;
static char op;

int isValidExpression(const char *str) {

int res;
char ops[10];
res=sscanf(str, "%f %s %f", &f1, ops, &f2);
if (res==3) {
    if (ops[0]=='+' || ops[0]=='-' || ops[0]=='^' || ops[0]=='*' ||     ops[0]=='/') {
    op=ops[0];
    return 1; 
    }
    else 
    return 0;
}
else
    return 0;
}

int getOperator() {
if (op=='+')
    return 1;
else if (op=='-')
    return 2;
else if (op=='/')
    return 3;
else if (op=='*')
    return 4;
else if (op=='^')
    return 5;
else return 0;
}

float getFstOperand() {
return(f1);
}

float getSecOperand() {
return(f2);
}

int InterCalc(char *my_string) {

fgets(my_string, sizeof(my_string), stdin);
if (strcmp(my_string, "exit\n")==0 ) {
    printf("Program ended\n");
    return 0;
    }
else if ( isValidExpression(my_string) == 0 ) {
    printf("Expression error\n");
    return 0;
    }
else
    return 1;
}

float getExprValue() {

int operation;
operation = getOperator();
switch (operation) {
    case 1:
    return (getFstOperand() + getSecOperand());
    break;
    case 2:
    return (getFstOperand() - getSecOperand());
    break;
    case 3:
    return (getFstOperand() / getSecOperand());
    break;
    case 4:
    return (getFstOperand() * getSecOperand());
    break;
    case 5:
    return ( pow(getFstOperand(), getSecOperand()) );
    break;
    default:
    return 0;
}
}

void CalcFilter(int a, char *str) {

float calculation_value;
printf("Press 'E' to display the invalid line or press 'V' to display      the valid line\n");
int choice;
choice = getchar();
switch (choice) {
case 'E':
case 'e': 
    if (a==0)
    printf("The line %s is invalid.\n", str); 
    else if (a==1)
    printf("There's nothing wrong with the line %s\n", str);
    break;
case 'V':
case 'v': 
    if (a==1) {
    calculation_value = getExprValue();
    //if (calculation_value > FLT_MAX || calculation_value < FLT_MIN)
    //  printf("The value of expression is beyond limits\n");
    //else
        printf("The result of %s is %f.\n", str, calculation_value); } 
    if (a==0)
    printf("The line %s is invalid\n", str);
    break;
default:
    printf("You haven't chosen the valid option of the switch\n");
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: Please **get used to** using the formatters common on this website. These huge chunks of text terrify me. No offense.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the first lines of your `InterCalc()` function

```
int InterCalc(char *my_string) {

fgets(my_string, sizeof(my_string), stdin);
```

`sizeof` is a compile-time operator.  `sizeof(my_string)` is the size of a pointer to `char` which for a 32 bit system is typically 4 bytes.

`sizeof` does not give the length of whatever string `my_string` points at.    It will not give 100 (the length of the array in `main()`).

You will need to pass the value `100` (or whatever the size is in `main()` if you change it) by some other means, such as an extra function parameter.

Comment: Hmm, but where should I pass this parameter? Besides, what's the relationship between the getchat() which seems not to work in an other function and a parameter value, which was not passed? Should I refrain from using fgets and use other function instead?

Comment: Continue to use `fgets()` to read a line of input from `stdin`.    As I said, pass the length by some other means.   For example, change `int InterCalc(char *my_string)` to be `int InterCalc(char *my_string, int my_string_length)` and pass `my_string_length` to `fgets()` as the second argument of `fgets()`.   Obviously the caller (`main()` in your case) needs to be modified so it passes two arguments rather than one.

Comment: 'Hmm, but where should I pass this parameter?' - well, wherever you cal 'InterCalc' sounds like a good plan.

Comment: It works thanks. Nevertheless I must admit that the reason why it works/didn't work is very elusive to me.

Comment: That's because you don't understand the difference between a pointer and an array.   They are very different things - despite having some behaviours that causes a mistaken belief they are the same -  and the result of the `sizeof` operator is one of the differences.